# iOS Objective-c run JavaScript in WebView depending on 3D force-touch shortcut

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am trying to load different JavaScript into my *UIWebView* depending on the 3D-touch shortcut that the user choose. 3D-Touch Example:

[image: Example]

I use following method to detect the different shortcuts:

AppDelegate.m

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {

        if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"MY_SHORTCUT_NAME"]){
            ViewController * view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
            [view loadWebViewFromAppDelegate]; // Method 'loadWebViewFromAppDelegate' is from my ViewController and runs as expected.

        } 
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(void)loadWebViewFromAppDelegate {

    NSLog(@"INECTING JS");
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location = 'https://google.de/';"];

}
```

But however the NSLog statement in *loadWebViewFromAppDelegate* is executed but *stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString* does not run probably. The JavaScript won't run. But If I call *loadWebViewFromAppDelegate* from the ViewController's *viewDidLoad* everything works fine. I assume that the WebView has not loaded completely when *performActionForShortcutItem* triggers, so the WebView is not able to receive the JavaScript yet. How to inject JavaScript, depending on the 3D shortcut, into a UIWebView correctly?

Comment: You might be missing some code here. You're creating a new view controller, but not presenting it. If your `_webView` is created in `viewDidLoad`, it won't exist when you call `loadWebViewFromAppDelegate`, since the `viewDidLoad` is not called until  the view controller's `view` is accessed the first time and is loaded (internally by `loadView`, which you should not call yourself). You should try calling `loadWebViewFromAppDelegate` from `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`. If you add the code where you are presenting your controller, I can give you a more specific answer.